# how to install panda via terminal in ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04?

Tags: python, pip

I want to install panda via terminal. I tried

```
sudo pip install panda
```

But it shows the error below:

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

Comment: Install `pip` (or `pip3`) by adding `python-pip` package ; ie. `sudo apt install python-pip`

Answer (score 2):

You should first install `pip` or `pip3` depending on your python version. You can check your python version by executing the following command in your terminal:

```
python -V
```

or

```
python --version
```

- If you have `Python 2.x`, then you should install `pip`, and then `panda` as follows:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pip
  sudo pip install panda
  ```
- If instead, you have `Python 3.x`, then you should install `pip3`, and then `panda` as follows:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pip3
  sudo pip3 install panda
  ```

Your installation should go on smoothly in your given case.

Answer (score 1):

Install pip (or pip3) by adding `python-pip` package ; ie.

`sudo apt install python-pip`

python 2.7 - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python-pip

python 3.x - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3-pip

Note: they are both in 'universe', so that repository must be enabled.